# Converting numbers and expressions

Tags: replacement, rule, homework

Trying to create a rule to convert negative numbers/expressions positive.

So far:

```
f[-x_]:> f[x]
```

Trying to extend this rule to floats such as -1.0 and expressions like -x but am quite lost.

Comment: Does this work `f[x_?Negative]:> -x`? You can also do `Sign[x] * x`. That has the benefit of being faster if applied to a `List` of numbers

Comment: @b3m2a1 `Sign[x] x` is just `Abs[x]`, of course. ;)

Comment: @J.M.isinlimbo -____- wow yes of course it is...

Comment: @J.M.isinlimbo that's not true for complex numbers though...

Comment: @Fraccalo, indeed, for complex numbers the relation becomes `Sign[z] Abs[z] == z`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try it as a rule.

```
rule = {F[-x_] -> F[x], F[x_] -> F[Abs[x]]}

F[-5] /. rule
(*F[5]*)

F[-x] /. rule
(*F[x]*)
```

This may not cover all scenarios, but it includes yours.

Answer (score 0):

An answer of poor quality:

```
f /: f[-x_] := -f[x]
f[x_ /; x < 0] := -x
f[-x]
f[-2]
```